# Google Cloud Distribution metric to line chart

Tags: logging, google-cloud-platform, charts, metrics

I have app deployed to random machine (out of any cloud), that sends logs into Google Cloud Logging in my GCP account. It always logs numeric value in certain field (used memory MB). All I dream about is line chart of memory consumption over time, simple as one you could auto-generate with some spreadsheet program, and I am trying to set it up in Google Cloud Console under Metrics explorer.

I have read [Configuring distribution metrics](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/logs-based-metrics/distribution-metrics), which seems to be the case - it gets numeric value from certain log field. But there is also bunch of options regarding histogram buckets there. And manual goes to Metrics explorer page where one could configure line chart as described [in this article](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/charts/charting-distribution-metrics#line_and_bar_charts), but those doc pages are also slightly out of sync with actual UI. There are many parameters in forms as aggregators, aligners, grouping, percentiles.. I don't understand why would I need them? All I need is all numeric values from log on Y axis and time on X axis, and I didn't find any clear examples on docs and google. I used Kibana stack previously for such scenarios and it was simple and straightforward.

What should I use for histogram/bucket values upon creating metric, and what should I use in metrics explorer to show a simple line chart?

Comment: It will depend on the application that you are monitoring, If you simply want to have a line chart then you can use Metrics explorer and simply fill in the resource type and choose a predefined metrics then the other options won't be necessary.

Comment: Sadly not helping. To define distribution metric based on logs I have to fill histogram information. How? If I leave default values there and proceed to metrics explorer, it prefills my metric name (leaving Resource type empty), but then there are 6 more fields to fill like aggregator, grouping. Can you please elaborate on those? What should be resource type if this is taken from log field?

Answer (score 1):

One important detail not mentioned in Log-based metrics guides:
"Logging doesn't backfill the metric from previous log entries".

Source here: https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/logs-based-metrics/troubleshooting

Personally I find it weird. If I want to analyze some fields in logs received in past, and I did not have any metrics about them, I can't build chart from logs without using some external tool that I feed with Cloud logs.